# organizing divs according to the available space on the page

Tags: html, css

I am trying to organize the divs in a page evenly and according to the available space. If there is enough space, I need divs to be horizontally aligned before going into the next line. I may have a number of divs under tab-content parent div. Any ideas how I can accomplish this? I inserted html and css.

html looks like this:

```
<div class="tab-content" id="tabs4">
   <div id="total_mem" class="all"> </div>
   <div id="total_cpu" class="all"> </div>
   <div id="total_disk" class="all"> </div>
   <div id="total_read" class="all"> </div>
   <div id="total_io" class="all"> </div>
```

```
My outer div's css looks like this:

.tab-content {   
width: 1400px;   
border: solid 1px #aaa;   
text-align: center;   
font-size: 20px;   
letter-spacing: 35px;   
white-space: nowrap;   
line-height: 12px;   
overflow: hidden; 
text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: How about providing a bit of sample content so we can see how these elements are intended to be used?  It almost looks like it might be tabular data...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make the parent container's width flexible, to use up all the available space on the page (not any more, not any less):

```
.tab-content {
    width: 100%;
}
.tab-content > div {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    float: left;
    width: 20%; /* Might have to adjust, depends on how many divs you want on each line */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To make the `div`s inline (horizontally) before going to the next line, use CSS `inline-block`:

```
.tab-content .all {
    display: inline-block;
}
```